# object[] from ReadOnlyCollection<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, object, readonly-collection

I have an object that I ended up with via a reflection call:

`object readOnlyCollectionObject = propertyInfo.GetValue(someEntity, null);`

I know this object is a generic ReadOnlycollection. It could be a `ReadOnlyCollection<Cat>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<Dog>`, etc. For argument sake, lets just say it is a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Even though a Dog derives from an object, I know that a `ReadOnlyCollection<Dog>` does not derive from a `ReadOnlyCollection<object>`. So even if I use reflection to call the CopyTo method I still need to know the specific type of ReadOnlyCollection, which is what I want to avoid.

I want to know how to get all the elements out of the ReadOnlyCollection as an array of object references without having to know the specific type (T) of the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many other answers mention Cast() and ToArray, those all have a problem with the type. As you say, you won't know which specialized IEnumerable your property will implement. However, you can be sure that they will all implement the non-generic ICollection interface.

```
ICollection readOnlyCollectionObject = (ICollection)propertyInfo.GetValue(someEntity, null);
object[] objs = new ArrayList(readOnlyCollectionObject).ToArray();
```

or

```
ICollection readOnlyCollectionObject = (ICollection)propertyInfo.GetValue(someEntity, null);
object[] objs = new object[readOnlyCollectionObject.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < readOnlyCollectionObject.Count; i++)
    objs[i] = readOnlyCollectionObject[i];
```

Edit: Forgot to update the cast from IEnumerable to ICollection

Comment: Problem is the first line won't compile because you cannot convert from IEnumerable to ICollection.

Comment: Changed. Must have been a hard-to-spot typo.

Comment: This solution is very neat because it does not care about generics at all.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use the [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method on the *readonly* collection and then convert it to an array of objects but, based on the fact that in c# arrays are *covariant*, you can simply do:

```
object[] objs = myReadOnlyCollection.ToArray();
```

*(edit)*

As Pop Catalin mentioned, the only works if `T` is a reference type. Use the Cast method otherwise.

*(edit2)*

Your update to the question changes things quite a bit ... I think that what you're trying to do is not possible. You want to cast to a explicit Type at *compile time* that is only available at *runtime*. In this case, the only way you have to access the collection is with reflection.

Comment: Arrays of reference types are covariant, this will only work if T is a reference type.

Comment: Please have another look. I updated the description to show how I obtained this object.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I will "Invoke" my way out of it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var myArray = readOnlyCollection.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your collection to a list of objects, then call ToArray():

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> s;
object[] o = s.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Works only in C# 3.5 because of the extension methods.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want a deep clone of the collection? If you want to deep clone try this code below for memory deep cloning:

```
// deep copy in separeate memory space
public object Clone()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms, this);
    ms.Position = 0;
    object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
    ms.Close();
    return obj;
}
```